# How to mock an instance method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a class and mock one of its methods, but I can't seem to replace the behavior of one of the instance methods with my mocked behavior. My code is organized like so:

`--src
----module
------__init__.py
------my_class.py
--tst
----__init__.py
----test_my_class.py`

`my_class.py` contains the following

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self):
        return 'Real Output'
```

My test file `test_my_class.py` contains the following.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.module.my_class import MyClass

def test_my_class():
    my_class = MyClass()
    assert my_class.do_something() == 'Real Output'

@patch('src.module.my_class.MyClass')
def test_mock_my_class(mock_my_class):
    mock_my_class.return_value.do_something.return_value = 'Mocked Output'
    my_class = MyClass()
    assert my_class.do_something() == 'Mocked Output'
```

The first test works just fine (no mocking involved so far). The second test, however, gives me the following assertion error. I expect the `do_something()` method to be mocked and to return "Mocked Output", and for the assert statement to evaluate to true. Where am I going wrong here?

`AssertionError: assert <bound method MyClass.do_something of <src.module.my_class.MyClass object at 0x1057133c8>> == 'Mocked Output'
E        +  where <bound method MyClass.do_something of <src.module.my_class.MyClass object at 0x1057133c8>> = <src.module.my_class.MyClass object at 0x1057133c8>.do_something`

PS. I've consulted the following resources without success:

- [Python mock class instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731477/python-mock-class-instance-variable)
- [Mocking Methods on an Instance Variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442510/mocking-methods-on-an-instance-variable-in-python)
- [Python mock: wrap instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768483/python-mock-wrap-instance-method)
- [How to supply a mock class method for python unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579535/how-to-supply-a-mock-class-method-for-python-unit-test)
- https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/python-mocking-you-are-a-tricksy-beast-6c4a1f8d19b2

That last link looked especially helpful at first, because I'm following one of the examples almost verbatim, but it still doesn't work.

```
@mock.patch("simple.SimpleClass")
def mock_simple_class(mock_class):
    mock_class.return_value.explode.return_value = "BOO!"
    inst = simple.SimpleClass()
    result = inst.explode()
    print(result)
```

Comment: A better way is to use patch.object instead

Answer (score 2):

Personally, `patch.object` confuses me. After reading [this article](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/python-mocking-you-are-a-tricksy-beast-6c4a1f8d19b2), I have decided to stick with `patch` only.

The problem with the patch in the question is that the `MyClass` patched is not the `MyClass` used in the test function. Refer to [this guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for a more in-depth explanation of where patch should be applied.

The path of the patch should be `tst.test_my_class.MyClass`, as shown in the code below.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest
from src.module.my_class import MyClass


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_class(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertTrue(my_class.do_something() == 'Real Output')

    @patch('test.test_my_class.MyClass')
    def test_mock_my_class(self, mock_my_class):
        mock_my_class.return_value.do_something.return_value = 'Mocked Output'
        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertTrue(my_class.do_something() == 'Mocked Output')
```

Run this command to execute it in a terminal.

```bash
python3 -m unittest discover
```

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate way to solve this is to use patch.object

```
@patch.object(MyClass, "do_something")
def test_mock_my_class(m):
    m.side_effect = ['Mocked Output']
    my_class = MyClass()
    assert my_class.do_something() == 'Mocked Output'
```